# __name__ vs __package__ in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If my understanding is correct, the difference between the `__package__` and `__name__` variable is:

- They are both the same for an `__init__.py` file.
- For any other files, `__name__` will be the full path, and `__package__` will be the directory of it.

Is this correct? If so, why is it necessary for python to add an additional variable in the scope for the `__package__` when someone could just as well get it from `__name__` ?

Example, for a `models.py` file:

- `__name__` ==> apps.main.models
- `__module__` ==> apps.main

Comment: Did you test your understanding? You'd quickly find it's wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__package__` and `__name__` are not about files, paths, or directories. If you want information about files, paths, and directories, that's given by `__file__`, which stores the relative or absolute filesystem path by which Python found the file for a module.

As documented in the [import system documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes), `__name__` stores the fully qualified name of a module, and `__package__` is used to support relative imports for main modules. Whatever module is run as Python's entry point gets the name `'__main__'`, so `__name__` is useless for relative imports there. `__package__` says what package to base relative imports from in that case.

For example,

- `random.__package__` is `''`, not a directory, because `random` is a (non-package) top-level module, and relative imports inside `random` are disallowed.
- An [implicit namespace package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), which exists across multiple directories, still has a single value of `__package__` and `__name__`, because `__package__` and `__name__` aren't about the file system. It has no `__file__`, because there is no file in the file system for an implicit namespace package.
- If you have a directory `foo` and files `__init__.py` and `bar.py` inside `foo`, and you run `python -m foo.bar` from the directory above `foo`, then `foo/bar` will be run as a module with `__name__ == '__main__'` and `__package__ == 'foo'`.

Comment: so, while writing packages with `__init__.py` in root and sub-package's folders, since `__package__` will be set automtically, do I need to worry about setting the attribute myself?

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala: You should essentially never set `__package__` manually.

Comment: Based on the above, is it more "correct" to create a logger based on `__package__` or `__name__`? i.e. `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` or `logger = logging.getLogger(__package__)`.

Comment: @Jenobi: Use `__name__`. Loggers are supposed to be based on the (fully qualified) module name, not the name of the enclosing package, especially since so many modules aren't *in* an enclosing package.